# Solving Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Write the first three terms in the series for:

$y= e^t$

find $y(2)$

I know I need to use:

$1+ t + t^2/2 + t^3/6$

What do I plug in for t though?

Answer (score 1):

You have a function $y(t)=e^t$. The notation $y(2)$ is shorthand for $y(t=2)$. So to find $y(2)$ you could simply substitute in $t=2$ giving you $y(2)=e^2=7.3891...$. You could also use the Taylor series, which is useful if you don't have a calculator.

So, the Taylor series expansion of $y(t)=e^t$ is 
$$1+t+\frac {t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+\cdots$$
So, to find $y(2)=e^2$ plug in $t=2$, knowing that the more terms you calculate in the series the more accurate your answer will be. So we get

$$y(2)=1+2+\frac{4}{2}+\frac{8}{6}+\frac{16}{24}+\cdots=7+\cdots$$

**Edit** Seeing your comments on the other answer, it seems your confusion lies in the Taylor series. The Taylor series for $y(t)=e^t$ has an *infinite* number of terms, 
$$e^t=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}+\frac{t^6}{6!}+\cdots$$
So if you only use terms up to $t^3/3!$ then you'll get an *approximate* answer, but you'll need to consider more and more terms in the series to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: So should the correct answer be 5 for y(2)?

Answer (score 0):

You have written y as a function of t.

y(t)=e^t

This you have expanded in your Taylor series, so just plug in 2. i.e. y(2).

Comment: So I did that should the answer be hole number but I get a decimal. Cause 1+2+6+(8/6)

Comment: Why do you think you need a whole number? Also 2^2/2 is not 6.

Comment: I rewrote the problem statement from the textbook. The answer in the back is a whole number

Comment: Once you include the 8/6 term then you will not have a whole number.

Comment: So the anwser should be 5 for y(2)?

Comment: If you are looking for a whole number using the approximation yes. But e^2 itself is not 5 nor a whole number

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Just threw me off cause on another problem we did t^2 instead and got a whole number still.

Comment: It just depends on how many terms you want to include i.e. how accurate you want your answer to be. The only time your Taylor series will equal the actual value is if you include an infinite amount of terms.